# Ignorar datos de un archivo y leer otros c++

Tags: c++, archivo, c++11

Estoy intentando hacer un código que dado un fichero con ciertos datos vaya almacenando la información en distintas variables. Os dejo un ejemplo del contenido del fichero

```
8     15.999000     21.808251      2.536749      0.000000
8     15.999000     21.808251     14.709249     12.172500
8     15.999000      9.635751     14.709249      0.000000
12     15.999000      9.635751      2.536749     12.172500
```

De los valores que hay almacenados tengo que ignorar los dos primeros datos de cada fila y almacenar los últimos tres. De estos tres datos de cada fila tengo que almacenar el primero en una variable, el segundo en otra distinta y el último en una tercera.
Lo que he estado intentando es leer todo el fichero, almacenar cada un número en un vector para luego intentar almacenar cada dato como he comentado arriba, pero no funciona.

¿Alguién tiene alguna sugerencia de como hacer para ir ignorando los dos primeros datos o cómo almacenar las columnas por separado?
Muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empieza leyendo línea por línea:

```
if (std::ifstream datos{"datos.txt"})
{
    std::string linea;
    while (std::getline(datos, linea))
    {
        // procesar datos
    }
}
```

Después puedes procesar cada línea a conveniencia:

```
std::stringstream procesar{linea};
int id;
double x, y, z, t;
procesar >> id;
procesar >> x;
procesar >> y;
procesar >> z;
procesar >> t;

std::cout << "Se ha leido la siguiente entrada: {x: " << x << " y: " << y << " z: " << z << " t: " << t << "}\n";
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVLdaoMwGL1OnuLD3bTgRG2t1Za@xG4HJTOpDdhYNG7@4LM7E5W5OrYFEc/xnOPnSaL7/TlKiIi77omLKCkogyNPc5kxcjvhL@6ypPKJwu8pp0CJTPMzZWfJcrla4wYjfoFVLmkYpqMd1LvG0FJLltJo1xghRcLxCMYe1HI8KwgC27Y1ch1rb@9dz4EBWt5m52@DAdmWrderMPoc9I8AZ2v5duCOAY5rOb7r/R4AgbXbeP6PAYsJHPfPhO//MB/hgFuMuZBwI1wMFT60esCzVvnUqhY91tqbkZb1Ii5iSLhg5NCTH1eesDEiZlLxK201B81a7Ylyz@3jl@5ZGrGcZI1WtioOqYE51Y80Ld767NKEyoTaBKnZyQSn0yScU@WCqRZMvWCkqmIcMUqL4QC9MLgSSBinKSQEch4XnAnJoL9lhJIQmjIEQ2lLbYBqhNUA6xHWA5QjHNJbvUUItbi/MMqYLDIBdr9rXfcJ)</kbd>.